# Do we have padding defaultValue in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to know if I could access to apple default value of padding in SwiftUI? currently I am using a custom found value that is 16 for iPhone, but it could be deferent in deferent device or in new update of Swift or SwiftUI, therefore I want make it future update and device proof.

```
import SwiftUI
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State private var paddingLength: CGFloat = 16.0 // Do we have something like: Padding.defaultValue to use it?
        
    var body: some View {
        
        Spacer()
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.red)
        
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding(paddingLength)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        
        Spacer()

        Button("update padding to 0") {
            
            paddingLength = 0
        }
        .padding(.bottom)
        
        Button("update padding to default") {
            
            paddingLength = 16  // Do we have something like: Padding.defaultValue to use it?
        }
        .padding(.bottom)
        
        Spacer()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You already using a default value when doing `padding()`

Comment: I know, but the question was founding out that value to use it in case we change it to other value, see my code example for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to get the default value but you could solve it by letting the length property be an optional and set it to nil for the default value. Only downside of this is you can't call `padding` with the length attribute only so either call it with edges set to `.all` or use another property for this.

Here is a solution with a property for edges as well

```
@State var paddingLength: CGFloat? = nil
@State var edge: Edge.Set = .all
var body: some View {
    Spacer()

    Text("Hello, world!")
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
    
    Text("Hello, world!")
        .padding(edge, paddingLength)
        .background(Color.yellow)

    Spacer()

    Button("update padding to 0") {
        paddingLength = 0
    }
    .padding(.bottom)

    Button("update padding to default") {
        paddingLength = nil
    }
    .padding(.bottom)

    Spacer()
}
```

Comment: you did not answered the question, maybe there is not even possible, but you salved in clever way, thanks

Comment: I did look at `EnvironmentVariables` and the properties for `View` but without finding anything. Let's see if any one else knows a way.

Comment: Good idea! I have a stomach feeling that apple used something like this: **@inlinable public func padding(_ length: CGFloat = 16.0) -> some View** LoL